# How to find which property is calling the subscribed method in Knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Is there is any way to find which property is calling the subscribed function, when we subscribe one function to more then one property ?

code example.

```
var self = this;
$(document).ready(function(){

var myViewModel = 
{
    FirstName : ko.observable("Bert"),
    LastName : ko.observable("pual")
};
myViewModel.FirstName.subscribe(self.notifyChange);

myViewModel.LastName.subscribe(self.notifyChange);

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
notifyChange = function ( newValue ) {// want to find which property(FirstName/LastName) is calling the function }
```

HTML

```
<body>
Enter your name:
<input id="source" data-bind="value: FirstName" />
<input id="Text1" data-bind="value: LastName" />
```

here i subscribed the "notifyChange" function for both FirstName and LastName. if any one value is changed means,it will call the notifyChange function, i want to know which property changes make the notifyChange function call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell who actually called the function.

One choice would be to use your `notifyChange` function, but `bind` it in each case to the appropriate property.  Now, `this` will be set to either the `FirstName` or `LastName` observable.  Doing a `bind` does create a wrapper to the function, but at least your actual implementation in `notifyChange` will only exist once.

```
myViewModel.FirstName.subscribe(self.notifyChange.bind(myViewModel.FirstName));
myViewModel.LastName.subscribe(self.notifyChange.bind(myViewModel.LastName));
```

So, `this` inside of `notifyChange` will be the appropriate observable.

Comment: I updated my question. `this` inside of `notifyChange`will give the observable, but that will not give the property name

Comment: @BalaKrishnan - a couple ways that you can get the property name.  One is to simply bind the function to the property name like `self.notifyChange.bind("FirstName")`.  Now `this` will be "FirstName".  Another option is give your observables names like: `myViewModel.FirstName.id = "FirstName";`.  Now you through `this` you can access the observable and read its name through `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question was asked and answered over 6 years ago. But maybe my answer can still be useful for someone.

The accepted answer is based on passing the observable as the context for the callback function.
By the way, you don't have to use `bind()`, you can pass the context as the second parameter to `subscribe()`:

```
myViewModel.FirstName.subscribe(self.notifyChange, myViewModel.FirstName);
```

Knockout uses `bind()` internally.

But, if you (like I did) can't afford to change the context within your callback function (I need properties and functions within that context), why not simply wrap your callback function in another function and pass an extra parameter to the callback function:

```
myViewModel.FirstName.subscribe(function (value) { self.notifyChange('FirstName', value); });
myViewModel.LastName.subscribe(function (value) { self.notifyChange('LastName', value); });
```

If you use this in a loop, say if you're enumerating properties of your ViewModel, you can wrap the whole thing in an IIFE like this:

```
// .. property is an enumerated reference to an ko.observer
// .. propertyName is a string identifying it (for instance 'FirstName')
(function (elementName) {
    property.subscribe(function(value) { 
        self.notifyChange(elementName, value);
    });
})(propertyName);
```